# Confusion with iOS Unit Tests

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, unit-testing, xctest

I might have a misunderstanding with XCTests in iOS Xcode.

I want to test if I am getting the correct json data after the user enters their input.

I have a obj c class file named HttpRequest.h and .m. Code in this class is mainly for connecting and setting up the HttpRequest to be GET or POST.

In my viewController X, there is a method that fetches the data and saves it in a dictionary.

My question is how can I grab the same dictionary fetched in viewController X to my test.m file to compare and apply it to codes like XCTAssertEqualObjects. In most of the tutorials I've read/watched, they basically establish a new json method to fetch the data **IN** the .m file. So I'm kind of confused to how unit testing should be done conventionally and structure properly according to my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're finding it difficult to test specific parts of your code, that's often a good sign that your code doesn't have the right structure.

For example, fetching data from a web service should not be the job of a view controller. You should have (and it sounds like you do) a separate class to achieve this.

Your request class should have its own set of unit tests, where you just test what that class does - your view controller should be calling the same methods. You'd pass in some known parameters (to simulate user input) and check the expected response.

What the view controller does with that response is a separate bit of functionality, and should have separate tests, with known inputs, not dependent on the web service.

Unit testing that depends on a web service being operational is a bit tricky - if the web service is down, your tests will fail, even if there's nothing wrong with your code. This is why people use things like OHHTTPStubs to return known responses to web calls during unit testing. Having said that, it is useful to have a set of tests that do connect to the web service which is useful for diagnosing if there is a problem at the service end.

I've written about a way to write your web service consumer classes in a way that facilitates testing and simplifies their use [here](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/01/02/nice-web-services/), which you may find useful. There is an accompanying sample project on github which includes unit tests.